# returned value from class method not being displayed in text feild php

Tags: php

I am trying to return the users values and display them in the update form, although they are not displaying.

**Form page:**

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$user->getID($user_id);
?>
    <input type="text" name="username" size ="25" value="<?php print $userRow['user_name'];?>" placeholder="username"required/>
```

**Class:**

```
public function getID($user_id)
 {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id=:user_id";
  $stmt = Database::getInstance()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$user_id));
  $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $userRow;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `$userRow` variable after you invoke the function.

As this function returns this variable, if you have your `$user` object, just change:

```
$user->getID($user_id);
```

to

```
$userRow = $user->getID($user_id);
```

Also make sure you call `session_start();` at the top, and that you instantiated the `$user` object: `$user = new UserClass` (or whatever class name you have there).

Answer (score 0):

You can get your required values by this way:

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$userRow = $user->getID($user_id);
?>
```

**What I have changed:**

You need to store your result in a 
variable than you can use it easily.